# Connect to Https Proxy using OkHttp Client

Tags: java, proxy, okhttp, apache-httpclient-4.x

Currently, I am using the Apache HttpClient with RestTemplate. We have a HTTPS proxy and currently connect by using a DefaultProxyRoutePlanner as given below.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(host, port, "https");
HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy) {
                        @Override
                        public HttpHost determineProxy(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
                            return super.determineProxy(target, request, context);
                        }
                    });
```

This allows me to connect to a Https proxy.

How can I achieve the same thing using a OkHttp client. I can see only an option to add java.net.Proxy which only shows the TYPE.HTTP as an option.

How can I achieve the same thing using a OkHttp client. I can see only an option to add java.net.Proxy which only shows the TYPE.HTTP as an option.

I will not be able to set JVM level proxy or System level proxy property as its running in a kubernetes pod.